# Empirical correlation for low reynolds convective heat transfer coefficient

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer, convection

I am looking for a heat transfer coefficient for a shape (rectangular cross section preferred, could estimate with flow over flat plates) in 2 m/s cross flow.

I have found a few empirical correlations from which I can find the Nusselt number and then estimate the heat transfer coefficient, but they are only valid for Reynolds as low as 5000.  I've combed through Incropera's Fundamentals of Heat and Mass transfer, as well as a few other textbooks - they all seem to report the same correlations. The Reynolds number for this estimation is ~100, since it is operating in air at near vacuum (~800 Pa) and only at speeds of 1-2m/s.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find this online: https://sbainvent.com/heat-transfer/convection/convective-heat-transfer-coefficient-flat-plate/
This does not put a lower limit on Re for the laminar flow correlation.

There has been a lot of research in this area! Nusselt number correlations for varying geometries and geometry patterns are available in droves online. Academic papers can be your best friend. While textbooks are an excellent place to begin a search, I would strongly recommend reading academic papers available online. Of course, discretion needs to be used on the validity of the paper and the applicability of the results. Hope this helps!